# How to make a list fit inside the parent div using scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I can't make a list fit inside the parent div (which is defined to be 100vh).
The list overflows the div. Tried to use flex and grid with no success. I don't want to use fixed size in pixel as the page has to resize with browser window.

The following codepen shows to problem. I appreciate any help

https://codepen.io/iamkky/pen/ExavYer

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #5050ff;
}

body {
  font-size: xxx-large;
}

#main{
  height: 100vh;        
}

#list {
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="title">title<div>
    <div id="list">
      <ul>
        <li>name 1</li>
        <li>name 2</li>
        <li>name 3</li>
        <li>name 4</li>
        <li>name 5</li>
        <li>name 6</li>
        <li>name 7</li>
        <li>name 8</li>
        <li>name 9</li>
        <li>name 10</li>
        <li>name 11</li>
        <li>name 12</li>
        <li>name 13</li>
        <li>name 14</li>
        <li>name 15</li>
        <li>name 16</li>
        <li>name 17</li>
        <li>name 18</li>
        <li>name 19</li>
        <li>name 20</li>
        <li>name 21</li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a demo for you with flexbox. Hope it can help!

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

div {
 border: 1px solid #5050ff;
}

body {
  font-size: xxx-large;
}

#main{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#list {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="title">title</div>
    <div id="list">
      <ul>
        <li>name 1</li>
        <li>name 2</li>
        <li>name 3</li>
        <li>name 4</li>
        <li>name 5</li>
        <li>name 6</li>
        <li>name 7</li>
        <li>name 8</li>
        <li>name 9</li>
        <li>name 10</li>
        <li>name 11</li>
        <li>name 12</li>
        <li>name 13</li>
        <li>name 14</li>
        <li>name 15</li>
        <li>name 16</li>
        <li>name 17</li>
        <li>name 18</li>
        <li>name 19</li>
        <li>name 20</li>
        <li>name 21</li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added some rules to ul like:

```
ul {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="title">title<div> /* The lack of a slash */
    <div id="list">
      <ul>
        <li>name 1</li>
        <li>name 2</li>
        <li>name 3</li>
        <li>name 4</li>
        <li>name 5</li>
        <li>name 6</li>
        <li>name 7</li>
        <li>name 8</li>
        <li>name 9</li>
        <li>name 10</li>
        <li>name 11</li>
        <li>name 12</li>
        <li>name 13</li>
        <li>name 14</li>
        <li>name 15</li>
        <li>name 16</li>
        <li>name 17</li>
        <li>name 18</li>
        <li>name 19</li>
        <li>name 20</li>
        <li>name 21</li>
      </ul>  
    </div> 
  <div> /* The lack of a slash */
</body>
</html>
```

dom Structure of the error

```
#main{
  height: calc(100vh - 2px);/* The border is 2 pixels and needs to be subtracted */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow: scroll` in main css like this

```
#main{
  height: 100vh; 
  overflow: scroll;
}
```